# Rails - Access sidekiq status via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using `sidekiq` and `sidekiq-status` gems for workers and tracking progress of them on web UI: `/sidekiq/statuses`.

For individual worker tracking `/sidekiq/statuses/job_id`.

How can I access progress info from a frontend via API?

On `GET /sidekiq/stats` I get reponse:

```
{
    "sidekiq": {
        "processed": 805,
        "failed": 62,
        "busy": 3,
        "processes": 1,
        "enqueued": 0,
        "scheduled": 0,
        "retries": 1,
        "dead": 0,
        "default_latency": 0
    },
    "redis": {
        "redis_version": "3.0.6",
        "uptime_in_days": "0",
        "connected_clients": "24",
        "used_memory_human": "1.06M",
        "used_memory_peak_human": "2.00M"
    },
    "server_utc_time": "14:50:29 UTC"
}
```

Can I do similar thing for `/statuses/job_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Sidekiq::Web source](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/873f1df9e0171a6eb1f9e6f50152f78e045b6df5/lib/sidekiq/web/application.rb#L234-L256) the only endpoints I see returning JSON are `/sidekiq/stats` and `/sidekiq/stats/queues`.

Remember, Sidekiq has many [API helpers for use in your Ruby code](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API). There's no reason you can't just create your own controller to pass job info to the frontend using the Ruby API. E.g. `Sidekiq::Queue.new("high-queue").find_job(jid)`

This also has the advantage of letting you set up more fine-grained user access control over the data rather than letting any user of your frontend have access to the Sidekiq API.

If you plan on making heavy use of this, you might think about upgrading to Pro which includes a [Pro API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Pro-API) with a more efficient `Sidekiq::JobSet#find_job(jid)` method.

Finally, if there's no API helper in Sidekiq remember that Sidekiq is all just Redis in the backend and you could write your own Redis queries to fetch the right data in the shape you want.

Comment: Thank you! I thing the best option for me is to get data from Redis and make my own controller. How can I access it?

Comment: My advice would be to read the Sidekiq source code and set up a development machine with Sidekiq. Connect to Redis via the CLI and just explore e.g. with `KEYS *` and `TYPE`.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminManns. I found it!

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to get stats of individual sidekiq queue, I have written a small gem [sidekiq_queue_metrics](https://github.com/ajitsing/sidekiq_queue_metrics) to do so. It provides individual queue stats on Web UI as well as provides an API to fetch the metrics.

```
require 'sidekiq_queue_metrics'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  Sidekiq::QueueMetrics.init(config)
end
```

**API to fetch stats:**

```
Sidekiq::QueueMetrics.fetch
#=> {
  "mailer_queue" => {"processed" => 5, "failed" => 1, "enqueued" => 2, "in_retry" => 0},
  "default_queue" => {"processed" => 10, "failed" => 0, "enqueued" => 1, "in_retry" => 1}
}
```

**Web UI:**

[image]